# ubuntu 14.10 install fail in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, 14.10

I have tried to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 32Bit
I am able to  install through virtual-box, but it fails after install and gives error:

```
- 0x7103e88e memory written fail is happened
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried completely deleting that virtual machine, and creating a new one and installing from the new one?  That sometimes does the trick.  I also recommend using vmware player.  Fewer errors occur when using vmware.  I used virtualbox for quite a while, and I always got some sort of error.  I then started using vmware, and i haven't gotten any errors since.
Tanner